# Morse Code convertor using string arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, converters

That example in C turns one character of English text, to the morse code equivalent. We have been tasked to read an unknown amount of strings in varying lengths and convert the whole string to morse. I know that  each entry in an array is a pointer to the one string's first character.

Off of the base code we developed, I'm not sure how to proceed, reading one character via user input is a whole lot different.

One other thought I had was that if each entry in the array is a pointer to the first character of that string, e.g.:

```
a[0] = "happy"
```

How could I ever just access one character because then I can run it through the code for one character at a time, but because it's an unknown number of strings and an unknown length read from an `input .txt` file I feel very overwhelmed.

Here is the developed code for doing one character via user input. Which I understand fully.

```
#include <stdio.h> /* getchar, printf, putchar */
#include <ctype.h> /* isalpha, toupper */
int main()
{
/* morse codes of the 26 letters */
char *morse[26] = {
".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--",
"-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."
};
char ch;
/* obtain input */
printf("Enter a letter: ");
ch = getchar();
if (isalpha(ch))
printf("Morse code of %c is %s\n", ch, morse[toupper(ch) - ’A’]);
else
printf("Error: %c is not a letter\n", ch);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of loops and array indexing?

Comment: @EugeneSh.        I guess I'm moreover confused about how use an array of pointers to represent an unlimited amount of strings of varying length and then access each character.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Develop step by step. Before even attempting the Morse code, read the input strings, and output each letter.

Comment: Try to `fopen` the file, check it worked, `fgets` each string, check they work, print them char by char (as ASCII value *and* as text char). When you finally convert to Morse code you must *check the range of the character* in case you have a `space` or a `newline` (which were encoded by short or long pause in the transmission!)

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for the detail. Very helpful. So fgets will just take everything in the file though or at least everything on one line. Assuming that we have several words on one line and the next etc, and we run fgets and it takes a bunch of words and puts them in the pointer array we mentioned when we called it.   Say the text file says "we are having a ball" It would store this in an array as so:   str[0] = w    str[1] = e  str[3] = \0     etc?

Comment: Please research `fgets()` you'll find usage examples. It reads one text line from the file into the buffer you provided. It's a lot more complicated to read the *entire* unknown file into an array of strings, before coding to Morse. I'm unsure of your task - is it allocating memory for arrays of chars, or is it simply Morse coding from a file? Your example does not even contain a loop or end-check. You could open the file and loop until `EOF` is read (to `int ch` not `char ch`), and convert what you find to Morse, as your example. PS don't forget the numerals `0` to `9` have Morse codes too.

Comment: @WeatherVane   I'll look into fgets, thanks again.     The task is to read a txt file of an unknown amount strings of unknown length into an array of pointers (where each pointer points to the first character of a string) Then converting to morse.